# Iframe with another iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I want to extract result of checking code. Website display in that code. I marked it in source code.

```
    <div id="ember332" class="ember-view backArrowContainer">
<div id="purchaseMeta">
<h2 class="flowStatus"> UŻYJ KODU PREPAID </h2>
<div class="gamertag">
<div class="title">
<script id="metamorph-2-start" type="text/x-placeholder">
***CODE STATUS WHICH I WANT TO EXTRACT***
<script id="metamorph-2-end" type="text/x-placeholder">
</div>
<div class="price"> Kod prepaid </div>
</div>
```

It is avaible when i go to this site: https://account.xbox.com/pl-PL/PaymentAndBilling/RedeemCode?token=W4HV8-6D6X3-3JVDJ-8PPG9-Q6BVR

I want to extract only CODE STATUS displayed when website will go to this adres. I think it can be avaible when i can use  in HTML but i don't know how. Please help me with extract this status.

Comment: Do you want to extract code inside an iframe which shows a different website? That's not possible.

Comment: @NathanParker it isn't only code. It is text display on webpage. I only want to extract that STATUS CODE in text form

Answer (score 0):

You can't extract anything from the inside of an iframe. There cannot be any interaction from the parent to the iframe. There can, therefore, be interaction between the iframe and the parent, but since you are not the owner of the iframe's webpage, this is not your case.

It's a security issue. People could get scammed if this wasn't this way. For example, designing a full-page iframe with a bank webpage and retrieving everything user types... Or designing a 1x1px iframe with a facebook page to see if your user is logged on fb and check all his/her personal information.

You can use a server-side language, such us PHP and get the HTML of that webpage using `file_get_contents()`